# what is the most recommended book to learn automata and formal languages?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

could you recommend a book to learn automata and formal languages? It is my first course in this subject and I would like a good bibliography with exercises and demonstrations.
In particular I would like some bibliography with examples, demonstrations, exercises of regular expressions.

I know there is a lot of bibliography but I would like to know in your opinion which is the best  for a newbie.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I personally adore [Sipser's book](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Theory-Computation-Michael-Sipser/dp/113318779X). It only covers the basics, but it's quite good.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I am going to check it